# Making a smooth transition between forms

Tags: winforms

I have 2 forms and want to alternate back and forth between them on button click in each. This can be done by opening the new form and closing the current one. However, from experience, if the new one takes time to fully show there can be a gap where no form is shown. I'm trying to use the Form.Shown event to avoid this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    var shown = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    form2.Shown += (ta, tb) => { shown.Set(); };
    form2.Show();
    shown.WaitOne();
    Close();
}
```

However, it deadlocks on the WaitOne statement. It appears the Shown event isn't thrown until after the click method is finished. How else might I do it?

Comment: This all happens on the same thread - the `Shown` event is posted and will be processed after your `button1_Click(...)` method is done - which never happens. You could try `form2.Shown += (ta, tb) => { this.Close(); };` instead (and remove the `WaitOne` and the other `Close`), but I haven't tried it so no guarantees

Comment: I had tried that earlier. It shows the new form briefly, then the old form and finally the new one. It would suffice if I could hide the new form until Shown is thrown. After the `new Form2();` and before the `form2.Show();` I've set opacity to 0 and then set it back in the Shown handler. That mostly works but sometimes during the Show() a couple of the new controls show up momentarily and then disappear.